# Hiding image alt text from Google Search?

Tags: html

I run a site that was recently indexed by Google (a few days ago). The main page has a few small images separating paragraphs of text. When I search Google for the site, it happens to show the parts of the paragraphs with the images, in the search snippet, which would be fine except it displays the alt text of the images, which looks bad.

Is there a way to stop this from happening, besides removing the alt text or toying with the images' placement?

Comment: Funny, people actually use it to index their pages

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web masters

Comment: Or deliver the page via PHP and if the client is from Google modify the page being delivered to not include the stuff you do not want them to have

Comment: Why do you have alt text that you don't like in there? If it doesn't look good in a search engine, where does it look good?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent this. But looking at your problem with a more technical perspective, you could off course:

- simply remove the alt text or use a better alt text
- remove the images from the DOM and instead put a placeholder element instead of it like:

  <div class="img-holder" data-src="/img/example.jpg"></div>

With javascript you could find all instances of .img-holder and replace them with an inline image with the given source (and alt-text when you also store that as data attribute).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent search engines, or other user agents, from doing whatever they like with attributes in your markup. You can add attributes, or change their values, in client-side scripting, and then the odds are that search engines do not see such additions or changes (since they normally do not run client-side script code).

If the images are just decorative separators between paragraphs, then you should simply use `alt=""`, avoiding this problem (and other problems too).